# How to update the values in a dict cleanly?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a piece of code which is iterating a list and then accumulate the values in a dict based on the keys, the ugly part is that I need to check if the key already exist in the dict, if not then I need to set the value to zero first.

I'm wondering if there's more elegant style to implement this:

```
for r in records:
    if not d.has_key(r[0]):
        d[r[0]] = 0
    d[r[0]] += r[1]
```

And further more, if the value is a list, then how to rewrite the following code:

```
for (key, value) in records:
    if not d.has_key(key):
        d[key] = []
    d[key].append(value)
```

Comment: Is your list containing tuples because you have used it like r[0] and r[1] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`dict.get`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11041405/1903116) method to get the default value, like this

```
for r in records:
    d[r[0]] = d.get(r[0], 0) + r[1]
```

The second argument to `dict.get` is the default value to be returned if the key is not there in the dictionary.

Even better, you can unpack the values, like this

```
for (key, value) in records:
    d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + value
```

Comment: Thanks and it really looks better! BTW, if the value is a list instead of accumulated numerical, how should I deal with that?

Comment: @ciphor You mean a gathering all the values in a list?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want to gather all the values into lists grouping by different keys

Comment: @ciphor You can do something like this `d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)`

Answer (score 3):

This is a common pattern when working with dicts in python so there is a **defaultdict** in the **collections** module. This lets you specify a default value for keys that are not in the dictionary. e.g:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
d[10] += 1

In [19]: dict(d)
Out[19]: {10: 1}
```

As you see, you don't have to check if the key exists in the dict if you use defaultdict.

```
d = defaultdict(int)
for r in records:
    d[r[0]] += r[1]
```